# why i cant break nor exit a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

for some reason when I type "exit" or "EXIT" the loop continues to iterate

I tried breaking using variables and the break statement

```py
obj = 1
while obj != None:
    a = input("enter a number:\n")
    b = input("enter a number:\n")
    try:
        int(a)
        int(b)
        print("succes!")
    except ValueError:
        print("you didnt enterd numbers")
        continue
    print("what do yo want to do?\n")
    donxt = input("for exit the program type EXIT, to continue tap CONTINUE:\n")
    if donxt == "continue" or "CONTINUE":
        continue
    elif donxt == "EXIT" or "exit":
        obj = None
```

Comment: `if donxt == "continue" or "CONTINUE"` is always true.

Comment: `if donxt == "continue" or "CONTINUE"` is not the right way to check for multiple values. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149/494134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `if donxt == "continue" or "CONTINUE"`

This is actually `if (donxt == "continue") or ("CONTINUE")` not `if (donxt == "continue") or (donxt == "CONTINUE")`.

The `"CONTINUE"` always evaluates to `true` so `(donxt == "continue") or ("CONTINUE")` is always true.

You want to do: 
`if (donxt == "continue") or (donxt == "CONTINUE")`

Comment: Also, you can just `break` instead of doing `obj = None`